# VB.NET Data from html page into variables

Tags: html, vb.net

I have the following html code:

```
<name>Username</name>
<kills>1</kills>
<ach_count>3</ach_count>
```

And on and on.....

I am looking for a code that extracts the value from  `<tag></tag>` and puts them into variable.

I don't want to use HTML Agility Pack, don't ask why.Also XML is not an option for me.

I hope you understand what i am looking for. If you have further question, ask.

Comment: You can use regex and parse the html code. Create regex to look to `<a-zA-Z>` `</ {a-zA-Z}>` look in-between

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i used xml.

html:

```
 <player>
<name>Tom Brown</name>
<kills>123456789</kills> 
</player>
```

vb.net:

```
Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

xDoc.Load("C:\test.html")

Dim name As XmlNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("name")

Dim kills As XmlNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("kills")

MessageBox.Show("Name: " & name(0).InnerText)

MessageBox.Show("Kills: " & kills(0).InnerText)
```